# EF Table-per-type perfomance

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type

In Table-Per-Type inheritance schema Entity Framework uses "CASE WHEN .. THEN"
When I have significant number of types, sql queries become extremely large and complex.
So, when I have more than 30 types (simple, with one key and one text field) in hierarchy can grow up to hundreds of kilobytes, and most part of it is "CASE WHEN ..."

So, my question is there any way to instruct EF to don't load all fields for all inherited types.
For example, if I have

```
public class A {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class B : A {
    public virtual string FieldB {get;set;}
}

public class C : A {
    public virtual string FieldC {get;set;}
}
```

when I execute query

```
context.Set<A>().ToArray()
```

it gets not only A.Id, but also B.FieldB and C.FieldC

this could be very important if I use context.Set().Single(a=>a.Id == itemId) with many inheritors of A query becomes enormous;

Is there any way to use DynamicProxy, to get only A.Id, and get other fields in lazy way by proxies?

---

Update:

Real-world example of deep-inherited entities that we use is documents:

For example there are base class IncomingDocument, with Id, Date, Number.

Then, depends of department, it could be BankingIncomingDocument (with AccountNumber, for example) , DepositaryIncomingDocument (with FinancialTool), etc. (up to 5-6 departments).

Then, for each department could be specific document, TransferFundsBankIncomingDocument, CloseAccoundBankIncomingDocument, etc.

Comment: I think you're abusing inheritance if you've got 30+ subtypes. It's _much_ better to use an interface if you want to make sure your entities have an `Id`. Then use inheritance where there's real polymorphism of related types. Inheritance is supposed to express different _behavior_, it is not data driven. But maybe you should tell a bit more if you really think this is a case for inheritance.

Comment: Added example, I think it should be inheritance, because TransferFundsBankIncomingDocument IS BankingIncomingDocument and BankingIncomingDocument IS IncomingDocument
 
Furthermore, often I would like to view all Incoming documents, all Banking documents, etc.

Comment: But is there any relevant difference in behavior that is programmed _inside_ the classes? If not, you may as well have one document class with some type fields. It much easier to query type fields than to query subtypes.

Comment: We use anemic domain model, so inside classes there are no logic, it used only as data container.
If I have one document with all fields - there will be redundant fields (I don't want to see AccountNumber in all Depositary documents)

This practice was good enough with another ORM, but when migrating to EF we facing with problems when have many inheritors.